# PHP How to return specific arrays from array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

New to PHP, I have one big nested array stored in $data which has many arrays. I'm trying to loop through this data and set my main $data array after than to only include the arrays that have 'swim' as true so 'Toe' below shouldn't be in the new $data if that makes sense. Not good with PHP loops sorry please someone help.

so e.g. im looping through first stage is fine foreach data

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => JOE' (length=7)
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=17)
          'letter' => string 'J' (length=1)
          'swim' => bool true (length=1)


 array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Moe' (length=7)
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=17)
          'letter' => string 'M' (length=1)
          'swim' => bool true (length=1)


 array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Toe' (length=7)
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=17)
          'letter' => string 't' (length=1)
          'swim' => bool flase (length=1)
```

This is what i'm using if I nest it further I can get to swim but how do I go through each and get the new data as before without 'Toe' because hes false?:

```
 foreach($data as $names){
    var_dump($names);
 }
```

Comment: Please look at how to traverse multidimensional arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297887/traverse-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: You could filter the array. There are many ways to do it, one is with `array_filter` but you can do it as well inside the `foreach` loop and `continue` on the cases not interested. Try the site search, there should be many examples available. Also inside the php manual on these.

Comment: can you show print_r($names), I don't know why the inner array has no key here from the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($names as $name){
    foreach($name as $value){
        echo $value['swim'];
    }   
}
```

Comment: I can do that and do checks but then how do I remove that false swim the main array from $data?